# ajax form not updating values

Tags: php, html, jquery

I've got this form that updates user information on db. However, this functionality is not working with ajax (works with a simple submit with refresh).

This postes form serialized data to the server
**jQuery**

```
  $('#commit-changes').click(function(){               

           $('#validation').submit(function(){
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#validation").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/user/updateuser.php",
                success : function(data){
                    $("#response-update").html(data);
                },
                error:function(){
                    alert("ERROR");
                }

            });
           });               
        });
```

Here's the HTML that outputs the markup
**HTML**

```
    $rcs_roles = $user->getRoles();
     $role ='';
     foreach($rcs_roles as $roles)
     {
        if($roles->role_number == $rcs_user->permissao) 
            $role .= '<option value="'.$roles->role_number.'" selected="selected">'.$roles->role.'</option>';
        else
            $role.= '<option value="'.$roles->role_number.'">'.$roles->role.'</option>';
     }

     if($rcs_user->activo == 0)
     {
         $activo = '<input type="checkbox" name="activo" class="on_off_checkbox"  value="1"   />';
     }
     else
     {
         $activo = '<input type="checkbox" name="activo" class="on_off_checkbox" checked="checked"  value="1"   />';
     }


     $response = '';

     $response.='<form id="validation" action="" method="post"> 
                                    <fieldset >
                                    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" 

value="'.$_POST['user_id'].'"/>
                                <legend>Actualizar Dados Utilizador</legend>
                                      <div class="section ">
                                      <label>Nome<small>Insira o seu nome</small></label>   
                                      <div> 
                                      <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]] large" name="nome" id="f_required" value="'.utf8_encode($rcs_user->nome).'">
                                      </div>                                      
                                      </div>';
 $response.='<div class="section ">
                                      <label> Email<small>Insira o seu email</small></label>   
                                      <div> 
                                      <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] large" name="email" id="e_required" value="'.  utf8_encode($rcs_user->email).'">
                                      </div>
                                      </div>';

 $response.= '<div class="section">
                                        <label>Permissões<small>Seleccione o tipo de utilizador </small></label>   
                                        <div>
                                            <select class="medium" name="role">

                                                       '.$role.'        



                                        </select>       
                                  </div>
                                  </div>                                      
                                 <div class="section">
                                        <label>Activo<small>Activar utilizador</small></label>   
                                         <div>
                                            '.$activo.'
                                            <span class="f_help">ON / OFF  </span> 
                                        </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="section last">
                                  <div>
                                      <a id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form" name="submit" >Gravar</a><a class="uibutton special"   onClick="ResetForm()" title="Limpar Formulário"   >Limpar Formulário</a>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>

                                </fieldset></form>';
```

And then the server side processing
**PHP**

```
$response='';
$id_user = $_POST['user_id'];
$name = utf8_encode($_POST['nome']);
$email = utf8_encode($_POST['email']);

$permitions = $_POST['role'];

if(!isset($_POST['activo']))
{
    $active = 0;
}
else
{
    $active = 1;
}

$user = new Users();

try
{
    $user->updateUsers($name, $email, $permitions, $active, $id_user);
    $response = "SUCESSO";
}
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
    $response = "ERRO".$e->getMessage();
 }

 echo $response;
```

Glad for all the help I can get

Comment: Have you checked firebug ? is 404 happening for server call ?

Comment: Wierd, but firebug seem to not even recongnize the method

Comment: @hardik, if I replace `$('#commit-changes').click(function()` with `function doUpdate()`, and then call it on click, it works! However, the error callback is called...

Answer (score 0):

From an initial glance, it looks like you aren't waiting until the document has loaded before binding an event handler. This means that #commit-changes doesn't even exist when you try to add the .click event handler.

To fix this in jQuery, wrap this around your entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do stuff
});
```

This function sends a callback to jQuery's document.ready handler, so that all the code only executes once the page is loaded.

Comment: Yes, it exists, altough I've ommited the code that pushes the HTML data from server.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .submit() function. something like this.

```
  $.post("modules/user/updateuser.php",{data:$("#validation").serialize()},function(response){
     $("#response-update").html(response);
});
```

on the php side try to `print_r($_POST['data']);` and please post the output.

Comment: Still, nothing happened... the new records aren't saved

Comment: I don't get a response from print_r either

Answer (score 0):

In the ***updateUsers*** function (in Users class) you try to update the field **nome** or **name** ?

You are suppose to use **nome** only right?

Comment: No. I'm updating all the fields that come from the form at once.

Comment: is there any chance you can put code in jsfiddle? or give development url so we can check whats actually happening in your page.