# jQuery ajax fails on form submit with link

Tags: php, forms, jquery

In the sequence of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121733/ajax-form-not-updating-values/11125356#11125356), the content I've got in a form is now updating the DB. However, when I click this link

```
<a onclick="doUpdate()" href="#" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form">Gravar</a>
```

The jQuery .ajax function fires the error callback AND updates the DB with the information as well.

Here's the code

```
function doUpdate()
{
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#validation").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/user/updateuser.php",
                success : function(data){
                    $("#response-update").html(data);
                },
                error:  function(data){
                    $("#response-update").html("Erro na submissão");
                }                
           });
          }
```

I'd like to get the success callback, in order to display a nice message to the user when it saves the data.

However if I simply do this

```
 <a href="#" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form">Gravar</a>
 <script>
 $(function(){
 $('#commit-changes').click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#validation").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/user/updateuser.php",
                success : function(data){
                    $("#response-update").html(data);
                },
                error:  function(data){
                    $("#response-update").html("Erro na submissão");
                }                
           });
          });
 });
 </script>
```

The "submition" doesn't work at all.

How can I solve this problem? Been stuck with this part for days! :(

EDIT - HTML for the form (This is also a response loaded in the begging of the page)

```
  $response.='<form id="validation" method="post"> 
                                <fieldset >
                                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="'.$_POST['user_id'].'"/>
                                <legend>Actualizar Dados Utilizador</legend>
                                      <div class="section ">
                                      <label>Nome<small>Insira o seu nome</small></label>   
                                      <div> 
                                      <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetterSp]] large" name="nome" id="f_required" value="'.utf8_encode($rcs_user->nome).'">
                                      </div>                                      
                                      </div>';
 $response.='<div class="section ">
                                      <label> Email<small>Insira o seu email</small></label>   
                                      <div> 
                                      <input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] large" name="email" id="e_required" value="'.  utf8_encode($rcs_user->email).'">
                                      </div>
                                      </div>';

 $response.= '<div class="section">
                                        <label>Permissões<small>Seleccione o tipo de utilizador </small></label>   
                                        <div>
                                            <select class="medium" name="role">

                                                       '.$role.'                                                 

                                            </select>       
                                      </div>
                                      </div>                                      
                                     <div class="section">
                                            <label>Activo<small>Activar utilizador</small></label>


                                         <div>
                                            '.$activo.'
                                            <span class="f_help">ON / OFF  </span> 
                                        </div>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="section last">
                                  <div>
                                     <a onclick="return doUpdate()" href="#" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form">Gravar</a><a class="uibutton special"   onClick="ResetForm()" title="Limpar Formulário"   >Limpar Formulário</a>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>

                                </fieldset></form>
```

Comment: are you expecting the object as json? if yes, then try adding `contentType: 'application/json'` to your ajax call

Comment: No, I'm expecting HTML as the response.

Comment: have you tried changing the `url` to `'/modules/user/updateuser.php'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution. Not the prettiest, as I wanted a pure jQuery solution, but, it works well.

Just needed to change the

```
<a onclick="doUpdate()" href="#" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form">Gravar</a>
```

To

```
<input onclick="doUpdate()" href="#" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form" value="Gravar" />
```

And now it works with the sucess callback firing.

Thanks for all the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your jQuery code inside a `document.ready` handler?

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // put jQuery here
});
```

The first example will work without `document.ready` (but doesn't make much sense because you're using jQuery anyway). The second won't.

Comment: Yes I did, but no luck with it either! The result is the same. It doesn't submits the form.

Comment: you can check what's in the `error` variable. Set a break point in the `error` callback and then check `error.responseText` (other properties as well), you might get more info on what's preventing the post

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe ~ I'm getting the impression that the AJAX call is not firing at all in the first place. At least, that's what I took from the question.

Comment: It's not firing if you do it in pure jQuery way. If you call an onclick and wrap it in that function, it submits, so, the ajax call is working, but at the same time, it isn't! :S

Comment: is your `<script>` tag like that in your code? I think you must specify `type='text/javascript'` ...

Comment: @JoãoDias ~ if that's the case, then I honestly can't see anything else from the code you've posted. Assuming that you've got the URL right, the syntax is a bit old, but definitely correct (as best I can see), and the only nick I can see would probably be if the `$('#commit-changes')` was failing somehow. That would happen if you've missed it in `document.ready`, but you say you've got that down. So... huh. :(

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe ~ the `<script>` tag without the `type="text/javascript"` should be fine as well, actually.

Comment: Yeah, the script tags are ok. @RichardNeilIlagan I've edited the post with the HTML of the form. Maybe it helps

Comment: @JoãoDias ~ are you loading that form via AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

In order to behave **doUpdate()** function as expected, Try this

modify the anchor tag **onclick** attribute to

```
<a onclick="return doUpdate()" href="#" id="commit-changes" class="uibutton submit_form">Gravar</a>
```

and also change the doUpdate function to

```
function doUpdate()
{
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $("#validation").serialize(),
     cache: false,
     url:"modules/user/updateuser.php",
     success : function(data){
         $("#response-update").html(data);
     },
     error:  function(data){
         $("#response-update").html("Erro na submissão");
     }                
  });

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't do anything different. It fires the error callback as well

Comment: If it's firing the `error` callback, you *should* be able to check what's inside `error.responseText`

Answer (score 0):

The jquery ajax success/error callbacks will fire based upon whether the POST request was received or not, it has nothing to do with what actually happens within the file you have posted to. It's strange you would get the error callback and have the database updated, but you can try and have the php file you are posting to give a response and then run success/error based upon that response.

In your php file you could have something like this:

```
$testQuery = "QUERY STRING HERE";
if(!mysql_query($testQuery))
{
    echo "error";
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "sucess";
    exit;
}
```

And then in your doUpdate function you can run the success callback and output based upon the html

```
    function doUpdate()
{
              e.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#validation").serialize(),
                cache: false,
                url:"modules/user/updateuser.php",
                success : function(data){
                   if(data == "success")
                   {
                       $("#response-update").html(data);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $("#response-update").html("Erro na submissão");
                   }                    
                }            
           });
          }
```

You can also use the "complete" callback which will fire even if the POST was not received, that wont tell you anything other than the function has been ran though

Comment: I've already have the PHP like that. I'm using PDO though. `try
{
    $user->updateUsers($name, $email, $permitions, $active, $id_user);
    $response = "SUCESSO";
}
 catch (Exception $e)
 {
    $response = "ERRO".$e->getMessage();
 }
 
 echo $response;`